# How can I get contextmenu for a polygon in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

In my leaflet code, I added markers (images) and vector images (polygon). I need to have a context menu for both, but In the case of markers context menu is visible, but not for the polygon. can anyone provide a solution for this, below is the code for polygon?

```
x = L.polygon([latpos,longpos],[latpos+1*scale,longpos+1*scale],[latpos+1*scale,longpos+3*scale],[latpos,longpos+2*scale],[latpos-1*scale,longpos+3*scale],[latpos-1*scale,longpos+1*scale]],{
            fillColor:'black', 
            color:'red', 
            fillopacity:1.0,  
            fillOpacity:1.0,
            contextmenu: true,
            contextmenuInheritItems: false,
            contextmenuItems: [{
                text: 'Show coordinates',
                callback: showCoordinates
                }, {
                text: 'Center map here',
                callback: centerMap
                }, '-', {
                text: 'Zoom in',
                callback: zoomIn
                }, {
                text: 'Zoom out',
                callback: zoomOut
            }]
        }).addTo(map);

function showCoordinates (e) {
    alert(e.latlng);
    }

function centerMap (e) {
        map.panTo(e.latlng);
    }

function zoomIn (e) {
        map.zoomIn();
    }

function zoomOut (e) {
        map.zoomOut();
    }
```

Comment: Could you add an example of the marker code that you've got context menus working on?  Also, how are you trying to add the context menus?  Are you using a particular plug-in? They're not part of the basic Leaflet library.

Comment: Also, there's a missing `[` at the start of the list of your polygon's coordinates, which would stop it displaying at all, but ought not to be related to the context menu not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a leaflet plugin for context menu [LeafletContextMenu](https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.contextmenu)